# File Download and Streaming Process with Next.js and CDN Integration

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js, download

I am attempting to create a download system for large files on my website. I am using Next.js, and my large files are hosted on a CDN. What I need is to download several files from my CDN, create a zip file, and send this archive file to the client. I already have this working with the following structure:

/api/download.ts:

```js
export const getS3Object = async (bucketParams: any) => {
  try {
    const response = await s3Client.send(new GetObjectCommand(bucketParams))
    return response
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('Error', err)
  }
}

async function downloadRoute(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
  if (req.method === 'POST') {
    res.setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=pixel_capture_HDR.zip')
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/zip')

    const fileKeys = req.body.files
    const archive = archiver('zip', { zlib: { level: 9 } })

    archive.on('error', (err: Error) => {
      console.error('Error creating ZIP file:', err)
      res.status(500).json({ error: 'Error creating ZIP file' })
    })

    archive.pipe(res)

    try {
      for (const fileKey of (fileKeys as string[])) {
        const params = { Bucket: 'three-assets', Key: fileKey }
        const s3Response = await getS3Object(params) as Buffer
        archive.append(s3Response.Body, { name: fileKey.substring(fileKey.lastIndexOf('/') + 1) })
      }

      archive.finalize()
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error retrieving files from S3:', error)
      res.status(500).json({ error: 'Error retrieving files from S3' })
    }
  } else {
    res.status(405).json({ error: `Method '${req.method}' Not Allowed` })
  }
}

export const config = { api: { responseLimit: false } }

export default withIronSessionApiRoute(downloadRoute, sessionOptions)
```

my download function in pages/download.tsx:

```js
  const handleDownload = async() => {
    setLoading(true)

    const files = [files_to_download]

    const response = await fetch('/api/download', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
      body: JSON.stringify({ files: files })
    })

    if (response.ok) {
      const blob = await response.blob()
      const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob)

      const link = document.createElement('a')
      link.href = url
      link.download = 'pixel_capture_HDR.zip'
      link.click()

      URL.revokeObjectURL(url)
    }

    setLoading(false)
  }
```

With the above structure, I display a loading UI on the client when they start fetching the files. Once everything is ready and zipped by the server, the zip file is downloaded almost instantly to the user’s download folder.

The problem with this structure is that if the user closes the browser tab, the download would stop and fail. What I hope to achieve is to stream/pipe the download and the zipping directly into the download queue of the browser, if that makes sense.

I attempted to use Readable Streams on the client side, which strangely seems to work because when I log the push function, I can see the values being logged and the “done” variable changing from false to true when everything is downloaded. However, the actual browser download of the zip file is still triggered when everything is ready, instead of “streaming” the download as soon as the user clicks the download button.

```js
  if (response.ok) {
    const contentDispositionHeader = response.headers.get('Content-Disposition')
    
    const stream = response.body
    const reader = stream.getReader()

    const readableStream = new ReadableStream({
      start(controller) {
        async function push() {
          const { done, value } = await reader.read()
          if (done) {
            controller.close()
            return
          }
          controller.enqueue(value)
          push()
        }
        push()
      }
    })

    const blob = new Blob([readableStream], { type: 'application/octet-stream' })
    const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob)
  }
```

I realize it’s quite challenging to explain what I want, and I hope it’s understandable and achievable.

I would greatly appreciate any tips on how to achieve such a solution.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, your objective is to enable streaming downloads of ZIP files generated on-the-fly, allowing users to start downloading even if the ZIP creation process is not complete.

I see that, in the original code, each file from S3 is fetched entirely into memory using `await getS3Object(params) as Buffer`.
And *all* the files are stored in memory before they are added to the ZIP archive. That could become problematic for large files or many files.
The ZIP file is created all at once and sent to the client, which does not start until all files have been fetched and zipped.

---

On the server side, I would propose to pipe each S3 response stream directly to the ZIP archive stream. That way, as soon as the server starts receiving a file from S3, it immediately starts sending it to the client.

Your `/api/download.ts` would be:

```js
import { PassThrough } from 'stream';

async function downloadRoute(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
  if (req.method === 'POST') {
    res.setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=pixel_capture_HDR.zip');
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/zip');
    
    const fileKeys = req.body.files;
    const archive = archiver('zip', { zlib: { level: 9 } });

    archive.on('error', (err: Error) => {
      console.error('Error creating ZIP file:', err);
      res.status(500).json({ error: 'Error creating ZIP file' });
    });

    archive.pipe(res);

    try {
      for (const fileKey of (fileKeys as string[])) {
        const params = { Bucket: 'three-assets', Key: fileKey };
        const s3Response = await getS3Object(params);

        const pass = new PassThrough();
        s3Response.Body.pipe(pass);  // Piping the S3 stream to PassThrough stream

        archive.append(pass, { name: fileKey.substring(fileKey.lastIndexOf('/') + 1) });
      }

      archive.finalize();
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error retrieving files from S3:', error);
      res.status(500).json({ error: 'Error retrieving files from S3' });
    }
  } else {
    res.status(405).json({ error: `Method '${req.method}' Not Allowed` });
  }
}
```

---

On the client-side, the client waits for the entire ZIP file to be received before initiating the download.
And it appends each received chunk to an array and finally creates a Blob object for download, allowing for a more real-time download experience.

Instead, you could create a new `Blob` object from the `ReadableStream` and create an object URL as the stream progresses.
Your client-side code in `pages/download.tsx` could be:

```js
if (response.ok) {
  const stream = response.body;
  const reader = stream.getReader();
  
  const link = document.createElement('a');
  link.download = 'pixel_capture_HDR.zip';

  let chunks = [];
  const pump = async () => {
    const { done, value } = await reader.read();
    if (done) {
      const blob = new Blob(chunks, { type: 'application/zip' });
      const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      link.href = url;
      link.click();
      URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
      return;
    }
    chunks.push(value);
    pump();
  };
  pump();
}
```

I have moved the link creation outside the `if (done)` condition. While the actual file download still begins when the stream ends (`if (done)`), this structure will be more amenable to future adaptations for streaming the file download.

For fully streaming downloads directly into the browser's download queue, you might have to consider using service workers and the `Background Fetch API`, but those are more complex solutions that require additional setup.

---

> Like you said: "the actual file download still begins when the sream ends", which is exactly what I was hoping to avoid.
>
> I want to stream the zip file directly into the browser's download queue; like a web interface for a NAS would do for instance.

Streaming a ZIP file directly into the browser's download queue as it is being generated can be a complex task, as the standard web APIs generally do not offer fine-grained control over the browser's download manager. However, you could utilize a [Service Worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API/Using_Service_Workers) in combination, as you mentioned, with the [`Background Fetch API`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Background_Fetch_API) (assuming it is [supported in your browser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Background_Fetch_API#browser_compatibility)). These technologies are designed for running background operations, including downloads, that can continue even after the user has navigated away from the page.

You would first register a service worker. Create a file named `sw.js` and another script to register it:

```js
// register-service-worker.js
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
  navigator.serviceWorker.register('/sw.js').then((registration) => {
    console.log('Service Worker registered:', registration);
  }).catch((error) => {
    console.log('Service Worker registration failed:', error);
  });
}
```

Include `register-service-worker.js` in your main HTML or as an import in your main JavaScript file.

Then, in `sw.js`, you would handle the background fetch:

```js
self.addEventListener('backgroundfetch', (event) => {
  const bgFetch = event.registration;

  event.waitUntil(
    (async function () {
      const records = await bgFetch.matchAll();
      const promises = records.map(async (record) => {
        const response = await fetch(record.request);
        const cache = await caches.open('downloads');
        await cache.put(record.request, response);
      });

      await Promise.all(promises);

      event.updateUI({ title: 'Download complete' });
    })()
  );
});
```

In your main JavaScript file, you can start a background fetch like so:

```js
const bgFetch = await navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then((swReg) => {
  return swReg.backgroundFetch.fetch('my-fetch', ['/api/download'], {
    title: 'Downloading ZIP',
  });
});
```

This is highly simplified and would require significant additional code to fully implement, including error handling, updating the UI, and so on.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time! I tried your solution and I am afraid there is still something I am not quite sure I understand. First I couldn't execute pass.end(s3Response.Body) because the s3Response.Body is a readable stream I believe? So I modified it this way: s3Response.Body.pipe(pass) which seems to do the trick. However I still don't understand on the client side how the download process can start right away because the download logic is wrapped in "if(done)" condition. So the zip file is downloaded by the browser only when everything is ready. Isn't it?

Comment: @Valentincognito Good points. I have edited the answer and amended the code to address your comment.

Comment: But like you said "the actual file download still begins when the sream ends" which is exactly what I was hoping to avoid. I want to stream the zip file directly into the browser's download queue; like a web interface for a NAS would do for instance. I checked the background fetch API but it looks not really well supported by all browsers.. But anyhow I'll dive a bit deeper in the subject.

Comment: @Valentincognito I have edited the answer to address your comment (with some clues, not a full-fledge solution)

Comment: Thanks for the update! I have to admit I'm a bit surprised this problem requires a complex and not yet supported by all browser implementation. But from all my researches your answer looks like the best thing I've got so far! Thanks very much for your time and wish me luck for implementing this!

Comment: @Valentincognito Good luck, and don't forget to, if possible, post here a link to your implementation, or at least an answer describing what you had to do :)